# Not sure which solution to choose (property used across two domain models, shared validation)

Tags: c#

I've got 2 classes with many different properties and one similar property:

```
public class A
{
    // Lots of specific properties

    [Display(Name="Dun and bradstreet number")]
    public string DunAndBradstreetNumber {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    // Lots of specific properties    

    [Display(Name="Dun and bradstreet number")]
    public string DunAndBradstreetNumber {get;set;}
}
```

I realise I have an abundance of choice and I just want to make sure i'm choosing the most semantically correct and popular choice.

**1:**-----------

Should I declare another class:

```
public class DunAndBradstreetNumber
{    
    [Display(Name="Dun and bradstreet number")]
    public string DunAndBradstreetNumber {get;set;}
}
```

and then make class A and B have pointers inside them eg.?

```
public class A
{
    public DunAndBradstreetNumber DunAndBradstreetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

or

**2:**-----------

inherit from the DunAndBradstreetNumber?

```
public class A : DunAndBradstreetNumber
{
    //...
}
```

**3:**-----------

declare a global function and put that in the get method of each DunAndBradstreetNumber?

```
public class A
{
    public string DunAndBradstreetNumber {
        get
        {
            // Run some function that I may need help on to apply property validation via attributes to
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Any more better choices?

My class A and B are domain models using entityframework if that helps at all.

The problem i'm trying to solve is to not have to declare the validation and display attributes twice in different models.

P.S - your opinion is fine... I just want to know the eventualities of the choice I have to make here (albeit its relative insignificance).

Comment: Using inheritance would be a very strange choice if your A and B objects ARE not DunAndBradStreetNumber ...

Comment: I agree, It doesn't seem right. Do you have a choice you prefer out of the above?